# Does the OpenSSL ASN.1 API support extensible types?

Tags: c, openssl, asn.1

I'm trying to use the OpenSSL ASN.1 API to implement my own custom types.  I expect to extend these types in the future, and the ASN.1 standard itself supports this via the concept of extensible types (see [here](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/2010/09/21/question-extensibility-removing-fields/) for an overview of what I want).  However, I can't figure out if the OpenSSL ASN.1 API supports this concept and if so how to implement it.  I've got the following structures defined using the macros supplied by OpenSSL:

```
typedef struct _TEST_STRUCT_V1 {
    ASN1_INTEGER* Field1;
} TEST_STRUCT_V1;

typedef struct _TEST_STRUCT_V2 {
    ASN1_INTEGER* Field1;
    ASN1_INTEGER* Field2;
} TEST_STRUCT_V2;

ASN1_SEQUENCE(TEST_STRUCT_V1) = {
    ASN1_SIMPLE(TEST_STRUCT_V1, Field1, ASN1_INTEGER),
} ASN1_SEQUENCE_END(TEST_STRUCT_V1);

IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(TEST_STRUCT_V1);

ASN1_SEQUENCE(TEST_STRUCT_V2) = {
    ASN1_SIMPLE(TEST_STRUCT_V2, Field1, ASN1_INTEGER),
    ASN1_SIMPLE(TEST_STRUCT_V2, Field2, ASN1_INTEGER),
} ASN1_SEQUENCE_END(TEST_STRUCT_V2);

IMPLEMENT_ASN1_FUNCTIONS(TEST_STRUCT_V2);
```

These macros generate encoding and decoding functions.  However, neither pair of functions works with the other version of the struct.

Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree?  I'm only trying to use OpenSSL's implementation of ASN.1 since I'm already using the library for crypto, but maybe a proper ASN.1 compiler would be the way to go?

Comment: The "here"-link seems to be dead :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luke,

You're probably going to have better luck with an actual ASN.1 compiler—there are several commercially available, but [Lev Walkin's free ASN.1 Compiler](http://lionet.info/asn1c/compiler.html) might fit the bill for your needs.

I'm not very familiar with OpenSSL, but a quick browse through the [asn1t.h source](https://code.woboq.org/crypto/openssl/crypto/asn1/asn1t.h.html) (among others) doesn't suggest that there's builtin support for declaring an extensible sequence. You're probably more motivated than I to look, but I confess I wouldn't be surprised to find they didn't include it. Extensibility can be a hard problem to solve, especially if you're relying on preprocessor macros for code generation.

In any case, relying on the OpenSSL code could cause problems in the future anyway: when the APIs or code change, you'll be forced to manually update all of your code to match. A code generator would (probably) do a better job of maintaining API (and ABI) compatibility while allowing somewhat more flexible code generation and language choices.

Comment: Yes, I've pretty much come to the same conclusion.  I'm not married to ASN.1, it just would have been convenient since we already have a dependency on OpenSSL.  I'm looking into alternatives and Google's Protocol Buffers looks pretty good.  I'll accept this as an answer since I don't think there is much else to say.